# How to get height for NSAttributedString at a fixed width

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, appkit, nsattributedstring

I want to do some drawing of NSAttributedStrings in fixed-width boxes, but am having trouble calculating the right height they'll take up when drawn. So far, I've tried:

1. Calling `- (NSSize) size`, but the results are useless (for this purpose), as they'll give whatever width the string desires.
2. Calling `- (void)drawWithRect:(NSRect)rect options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options` with a rect shaped to the width I want and `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin` in the options, exactly as I'm using in my drawing. The results are ... difficult to understand; certainly not what I'm looking for. (As is pointed out in a number of places, including [this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2006/Apr/msg01540.html) Cocoa-Dev thread).
3. Creating a temporary NSTextView and doing:
   `[[tmpView textStorage] setAttributedString:aString];

   [tmpView setHorizontallyResizable:NO];

   [tmpView sizeToFit];` 
   When I query the frame of tmpView, the width is still as desired, and the height is often correct ... until I get to longer strings, when it's often half the size that's required. (There doesn't seem to be a max size being hit: one frame will be 273.0 high (about 300 too short), the other will be 478.0 (only 60-ish too short)).

I'd appreciate any pointers, if anyone else has managed this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer *is* to use
 `- (void)drawWithRect:(NSRect)rect options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options`
but the `rect` you pass in should have 0.0 in the dimension you want to be unlimited (which, er, makes perfect sense). Example [here](http://teilweise.tumblr.com/post/293948288/boundingrectwithsize-options-attributes).

Comment: This answer is outdated. [Graham's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2460091/39155) below is the correct method as of 2014.

Comment: This is outdated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54980862/326242 for the up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 31):

```
-[NSAttributedString boundingRectWithSize:options:]
```

You can specify `NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics` to get [union of all glyph bounds](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2006/Feb/msg00564.html).

Unlike `-[NSAttributedString size]`, the returned `NSRect` represents the dimensions of the area that would change if the string is drawn.

As @Bryan comments, [`boundingRectWithSize:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/boundingRectWithSize:options:) is deprecated (not recommended) in OS X 10.11 and later. This is because string styling is now dynamic depending on the context.

For OS X 10.11 and later, see Apple's [Calculating Text Height](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/StringHeight.html) developer documentation.

Comment: It seems that if you use `NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics` and there are no glyphs that this will return `0`. Is there a way to handle both situations? Or must you some how know or keep track of whether you added a glyph? (Tested on iOS 8.)

Comment: It makes sense that a string with no visible content would return a zero sized rect. Are you seeing new behaviour on iOS 8 compared to iOS 7?

Comment: I meant that if you have an `NSAttributedString` with text (and no glyphs) and you use `NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics` the size is `CGSizeZero`. So it seems like you have to know if there are glyphs before you decide how to get the size...

Comment: Is it possible to have text without [glyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph)? Is this a common situation?

Comment: Ah, terminology issue. By glyphs I meant `NSTextAttachments` images in the `NSAttributedString.` But from your response I gather that `NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics` should be able to be used regardless of NSTextAttachments?

Comment: Yes, assuming you want the [bounds of the affected pixels](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSStringDrawingOptions). The best way is to create a small test app and confirm the behaviour matches your needs.

Comment: NOTE: You must pass the NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin option for this approach to return non-nonsense results. See my answer below for more information.

Comment: Bad news: this method is deprecated starting on OS 10.11 AND it no longer returns the correct height. It's too low. Works great on 10.10 and below, though.

Comment: This is outdated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54980862/326242 for the up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 12):

I have a complex attributed string with multiple fonts and got incorrect results with a few of the above answers that I tried first. Using a UITextView gave me the correct height, but was too slow for my use case (sizing collection cells). I wrote swift code using the same general approach described in the [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/StringHeight.html) referenced previously and described by Erik. This gave me correct results with must faster execution than having a UITextView do the calculation.

```
private func heightForString(_ str : NSAttributedString, width : CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let ts = NSTextStorage(attributedString: str)

    let size = CGSize(width:width, height:CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)

    let tc = NSTextContainer(size: size)
    tc.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0

    let lm = NSLayoutManager()
    lm.addTextContainer(tc)

    ts.addLayoutManager(lm)
    lm.glyphRange(forBoundingRect: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size), in: tc)

    let rect = lm.usedRect(for: tc)

    return rect.integral.size.height
}
```

Comment: This solved my issue. I have an attributed string with a lot of attributes all with different ranges and the typical measurement APIs weren't quite working. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: This is outdated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54980862/326242 for the up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in Jerry Krinock's great (OS X only) [`NS(Attributed)String+Geometrics`](http://www.sheepsystems.com/sourceCode/sourceStringGeometrics.html) category, which is designed to do all sorts of string measurement, including what you're looking for.

Comment: That code appears to be Mac specific. It won't help with iOS development.

Comment: You're right, the question was about `NSTextView`, which is a Mac class. I'm not even sure iOS had `NSAttributedString` when I answered this question.

Comment: Late input, but just a heads up: I've had problems with NS(Attributed)String+Geometrics consistently underestimating the height that long strings require. Until now, I've actually just fudged the result by adding an extra 25%. I'm now looking for a newer, better solution. I do not think NS(Attributed)String+Geometrics is working well on 10.9, 10.10 and 10.11.

Comment: This is outdated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54980862/326242 for the up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 3):

On OS X 10.11+, the following method works for me (from Apple's [Calculating Text Height](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/StringHeight.html) document)

```
- (CGFloat)heightForString:(NSAttributedString *)myString atWidth:(float)myWidth
{
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:myString];
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithContainerSize:
        NSMakeSize(myWidth, FLT_MAX)];
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
    [layoutManager glyphRangeForTextContainer:textContainer];
    return [layoutManager
        usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer].size.height;
}
```

Comment: This is outdated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54980862/326242 for the up-to-date answer.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, after tons of trouble with `boundingRectWithSize:` thanks!

Comment: @AndrewKoster you should consider deleting your comment(s). It has confused me and deterred me from trying a solution that ended up working for me over the one you say is the up-to-date answer.

Comment: ... However this only seemed to work when I provided a value other than FLT_MAX for the width.

Comment: @NoahNuebling My link is pointing to the answer by @ZAFAR007. Stack Overflow's CSS is slightly off, which is unfortunate. @ZAFAR007's answer is in Swift and uses `boundingRect`. It is both simpler than this answer and, from my tests, worked where this answer did not.

Comment: @AndrewKoster I was using attributed strings with bold text and links (including underlines). The `boundingRect` method seemed to work pretty well but broke in some edge cases. It slightly underestimated the width (IIRC). I tried lots of things to make it work but it just didn't for me. A comment above even mentions that the `boundingRect` method is deprecated in 10.11+. In contrast, the `layourManager` solution is straight from Apple docs, which aren't deprecated as far as I can tell. So I think this solution has a higher chance of working for most people.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3:

```
let attributedStringToMeasure = NSAttributedString(string: textView.text, attributes: [
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "GothamPro-Light", size: 15)!,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: ClickUpConstants.defaultBlackColor
])

let placeholderTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: widthOfActualTextView, height: 10))
placeholderTextView.attributedText = attributedStringToMeasure
let size: CGSize = placeholderTextView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: widthOfActualTextView, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

height = size.height
```

This answer works great for me, unlike the other ones which were giving me incorrect heights for larger strings.

If you want to do this with regular text instead of attributed text, do the following:

```
let placeholderTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: ClickUpConstants.screenWidth - 30.0, height: 10))
placeholderTextView.text = "Some text"
let size: CGSize = placeholderTextView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: widthOfActualTextView, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

height = size.height
```

Comment: This is outdated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54980862/326242 for the up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.2**

```
let attributedString = self.textView.attributedText
let rect = attributedString?.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: self.textView.frame.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], context: nil)
print("attributedString Height = ",rect?.height)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just wasted a bunch of time on this, so I'm providing an additional answer to save others in the future. Graham's answer is 90% correct, but it's missing one key piece:

To obtain accurate results with `-boundingRectWithSize:options:` **you MUST pass the following options**:

```
NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
```

If you omit the lineFragmentOrigin one, you'll get nonsense back; the returned rect will be a single line high and won't at all respect the size you pass into the method.

Why this is so complicated and so poorly documented is beyond me. But there you have it. Pass those options and it'll work perfectly (on OS X at least).

Comment: Also: this assumes you've got an NSAttributedString created with a given font and the NSParagraphStyle you're looking for -- in my case, that's a left-aligned, word-wrapping, no-hyphenation paragraph style. Don't forget to create that when you create your attributedString.

Comment: This method is deprecated on 10.11+ and no longer works correctly; the returned height is too small on El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSAttributedString method

```
- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context
```

The size is the constraint on the area, the calculated area width is restricted to the specified width whereas the height is flexible based on this width. One can specify nil for context if that's not available. To get multi-line text size, use NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin for options.

Comment: This is outdated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54980862/326242 for the up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not a single answer on this page worked for me, nor did that ancient old Objective-C code from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/StringHeight.html).  What I finally did get to work for a `UITextView` is first setting its `text` or `attributedText` property on it and then calculating the size needed like this:

```
let size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
```

Works perfectly.  Booyah!

Comment: Finally something that actually works.

Answer (score 1):

As lots of guys mentioned above, and base on my test.

I use `open func boundingRect(with size: CGSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions = [], context: NSStringDrawingContext?) -> CGRect` on iOS like this bellow:

```
let rect = attributedTitle.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width:200, height:0), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
```

Here the **`200` is the fixed width** as your expected, **height I give it 0** since I think it's better to kind tell API height is **unlimited**.

Option is not so important here，I have try `.usesLineFragmentOrigin` or `.usesLineFragmentOrigin.union(.usesFontLeading)` or `.usesLineFragmentOrigin.union(.usesFontLeading).union(.usesDeviceMetrics)`, it give same result.

And the result is expected as my though.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**I found helper class to find height and width of attributedText (Tested code)**

https://gist.github.com/azimin/aa1a79aefa1cec031152fa63401d2292

Add above file in your project

**How to use**

```
let attribString = AZTextFrameAttributes(attributedString: lbl.attributedText!)
let width : CGFloat = attribString.calculatedTextWidth()
print("width is :: >> \(width)")
```

Comment: That helper class does the calculation twice (height and width). Calculating string size is not cheap so it's an unnecessary overhead if you're doing a lot of layout.