# How to calculate the height of an NSAttributedString with given width in iOS 6

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, bounding-box

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get height for NSAttributedString at a fixed width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282629/how-to-get-height-for-nsattributedstring-at-a-fixed-width)

Now NSAttributedString is available in iOS 6. For layout purposes, I want to know how to calculate the required height of an NSAttributedString under fixed width. I'm looking for something that's equivalent to NSString's `- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size` but for NSAttributedString.

To calculate the drawing size of NSAttributedStrings, there are two methods available:

1. `- (CGSize)size` can't be used because it does not take any width into consideration.
2. I tried `- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context`, but somehow it doesn't give me the correct height. I think the method is buggy. If I run the following code, it gives me `bounding size: 572.324951, 19.000000` ignoring the given width of 200. It should give me something like 100 of height.

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor]};
    [attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Attributed String\n" attributes:attributes]];
    [attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Attributed String\n" attributes:attributes]];
    [attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Attributed String\n" attributes:attributes]];
    [attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Attributed String\n" attributes:attributes]];
    [attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Attributed String\n" attributes:attributes]];

    CGRect frame = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(200, 1000) options:0 context:nil];
    NSLog(@"bounding size: %f, %f", frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
```

There are other methods available for Mac OS X, but not for iOS.

Comment: @SimonGoldeen That's not a good duplicate. The accepted answer doesn't actually give the height and the other answers don't show the proper way to use the `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:` method.

Comment: In Swift, this can be done by `let desiredWidth: CGFloat = 300; let rect = attrStr.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: desiredWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], context: nil)`

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Option 2 does work in iOS with the proper parameters.

```
NSAttributedString *attrStr = ... // your attributed string
CGFloat width = 300; // whatever your desired width is
CGRect rect = [attrStr boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, 10000) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];
```

Without the proper values for the `options` parameter you will get the wrong height.

It is also required that `attrStr` contains a font attribute. Without a font, there is no way to properly calculate the size.

Comment: Hmm... not working for me. I seem to get good calculations about only half the time.

Comment: It does not work for me either. It is way off like it is not accounting for font size.

Comment: Finally a simple and functional way to calculate the size of a `NSAttributedString` that works even with very complex formatting. Other answers to similar questions go as far as creating a category on  NSAttributedString - thankfully it does not have to be that hard.

Comment: @Dogweather In my experience, the NSAttributedString must have a NSFontAttributeName key to be sized correctly.

Comment: @bentford THANK YOU for that tip - I was creating an attributed string with the -initWithString: method, and that resulted in completely arbitrary computed sizes. Using -initWithString:attributes: works!

Comment: See my answer for how I worked around a problem where boundingRectWithSize on UILabel's attributedText would always return the height for a single line http://stackoverflow.com/a/28226095/115676

Comment: I have discovered an interesting text pattern that always results in an incorrect height measurement:

some text containing "[]" followed by a singular, soft-returned word (that triggers an implicit word-wrap)

Comment: We probably want to use `CGFLOAT_MAX` for the size parameter, rather than `10000` which, at some point in time, might actually fit on our screens...

Comment: Can't set an attributedString before BoundingRectWithSize it gives me No visible @interface blahblah. How does this work?

Comment: Hii... i also getting some time perfect height but not all time.. when my string is too large at that time i am getting wrong height

Comment: If set lineSpacing, it did not get the correct height.

Comment: It works depend on the text. It doesn't work for all cases. [textView sizeThatFits:] seems to work better. But always adds an extra space at the end

Comment: The results arent reliable on screen.

Comment: @AlexD to add to this old thread, use `usesLineFragmentOrigin` to make it multi-line