# How to set label and its dynamic text to center of uiview

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiview, uilabel

How to set label and its dynamic text to center of uiview.

```
 myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,self.view.frame.size.width,32)];
    [myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.view addSubView:myView];

    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myView.frame.size.width/2,10,0, 12)];
    [myLabel setFont:[UIFont Helvetica12]];
    [myLabel setText:[listDiction objectForKey @"dynaimicText"];
    [myLabel sizeToFit];
    myLabel.center = myView.center;
    [myView addSubview:myLabel];
```

Need your advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

replace your lines with this order,

```
[myView addSubview:myLabel];
[myLabel sizeToFit];
myLabel.center = myView.center;
```

but wait, if your text is dynamic then, you've to add, `myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;` (for multiple line) also if your text size is > myView height then text's will be clipped when it'll increase myView height.

For that, you've to calculate label text size and resize your myView before creating myLabel.

This question [Calculating number of lines of dynamic UILabel (iOS7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784183/calculating-number-of-lines-of-dynamic-uilabel-ios7) may help.

Comment: text is dynamic but maximum length for  dynamic data is 15 so mylabel.numberoflines is not need.  after replace UILabel is not visible at all.