# UILabel sizeThatFits not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uilabel

I'm trying to calculate the height for a UITableViewCell so I've defined a class method that looks like this

```
+ (CGFloat)heightWithText:(NSString *)text
{
    SizingLabel.text = text;
    [SizingLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(LABEL_WIDTH, CGFLOAT_MAX)];

    return (TOP_MARGIN + SizingLabel.frame.size.height + BOTTOM_MARGIN);
}
```

I've defined SizingLabel like this:

```
+ (void)initialize
{
    SizingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    SizingLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    SizingLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
}
```

However, if i stick a breakpoint in the -heightWithText: method, i notice that the dimensions of SizingLabel never change and i thus get an incorrect value. Why is that?

Comment: -(CGSize)sizeThatFits: returns a size in which your text get fit for your Label.

Comment: ahh ok does it not actually resize the label as well?

Comment: yes, It just returns you a size.

Comment: @SeanDanzeiser:Multilines allowed to you label?

Comment: tested, boundingRectWithSize methods can not calculate correct when your attributes only apply to your range of text. if your attributes apply to all range of your text, it works ok. but since you didn't mention you want it apply to attribute text at the first time in your question, it's unfair your downvote my answer

Comment: i didn't down vote it.

Comment: i'm needing to know the same stuff, nice question in my eyes *upvoted* (although capital camel casing for property/variable made me sad!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
+ (CGFloat)heightWithText:(NSString *)text
{
    SizingLabel.text = text;
    CGSize labelSize = [SizingLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(LABEL_WIDTH, CGFLOAT_MAX)];

    return (TOP_MARGIN + labelSize.height + BOTTOM_MARGIN);
}
```

Comment: Works for UILabel if font is set for the label.

Comment: @OlgaVogue No, it only works sometimes. sizeThatFits is notoriously buggy.

Answer (score 7):

As said above, `sizeThatFits:` (and thus `sizeToFit`) do not work well with `UILabel` objects.

You better use the preferred `textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:` method:

```
+ (CGFloat)heightWithText:(NSString *)text
{
    resizingLabel.text = text;
    CGSize labelSize = [resizingLabel textRectForBounds:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, LABEL_WIDTH, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                 limitedToNumberOfLines:0].size; // No limit

    return (TOP_MARGIN + labelSize.height + BOTTOM_MARGIN);
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me, also, you should follow the naming convention and start variable names with lower case (or is `SizingLabel` supposed to be a class?)

Comment: `SizingLabel`must have been an automatic rename problem. Also you or anyone can edit posts ;)  As for this not working. What part is the problem? Basically this code only uses the built-in `textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:` which should always work.

Comment: it was returning a size that did not really reflect the size the text would be given. After all, it does not take into account the font. I ended up using `NSString boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`.

Comment: It does take into account the `UILabel` font and parameters. You can set it up all in IB and then have an accurate measure. That is why I prefer it than trying to recreate the label configuration with `NSString`. As for your problem, is the built-in method returning a wrong value or is it the accompanying adjustments? And the `SizingLabel` came from the original question.

Comment: If you believe [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409897/how-to-calculate-the-height-of-an-nsattributedstring-with-given-width-in-ios-6#comment31619039_14410019), it seems that it does not work correctly when the attributed string does not contain a `NSFontAttributeName`.

Comment: I've used sizeThatFits: for years, and it seems to be a bit of voodoo, sometimes works and sometimes just doesn't.  Using textRectForBounds is perfect!

Answer (score 3):

Do this in your Custom Cell Class:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        //Message Label
        lbl_name = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 25)];            

        [lbl_name setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0f]];
        lbl_name.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        lbl_name.numberOfLines = 0;
        [lbl_name sizeToFit];
        [self.contentView addSubview:lbl_name];

        //Time 
    }
    return self;
}    

-(void)resizeNameLabel:(NSString *)text
{
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(300 , 20000.0f);
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [lbl_name setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, MAX(size.height, 25.0f))];//300 Label Width
    [lbl_name setText:text];
}
```

Do this in main class..

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = (CustomCell *)[[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
        [((CustomCell *)cell) resizeNameLabel:text];

    return cell;
}
```

Just do like this...

Answer (score 0):

below code is to calculate the rect for dynamic text length (ios7 version)

```
- (CGRect)labelFrameWithText:(NSString *)text
{
    CGRect rect;

    // the font of your text
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0]; 
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};

    // the first parametric CGSize is the max size that the rect's size can be
    CGRect boundingRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(youImageWidth, 100.0)
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           attributes:attributes
                                              context:nil];

    //the rect of the UILabel
    //This method returns fractional sizes (in the size component of the returned CGRect); to use a returned size to size views, you must use raise its value to the nearest higher integer using the ceil function.
    rect = CGRectMake(yourLabelOriginX,
                      yourLabelOriginY,
                      ceil(boundingRect.size.width),
                      ceil(boundingRect.size.height));

    return rect;
}
```

and after you get the rect, use it to calculate your cell size

----------------older version-------------------

```
CGSize contentSize = [content sizeWithFont:font
                             constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, maxHeight)
                                 lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Comment: the (NSDictionary) attributes is where you set your text attributes

Answer (score 0):

For simple sizing of UILabels that have attributed text, I added this category to UILabel.

```
@implementation UILabel (PAUtils)

- (CGSize)jb_attributedSizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    CGRect textRect = [self.attributedText boundingRectWithSize:size options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) context:nil];
    return textRect.size;
}

@end
```

Two things to note:

1. When not setting `attributedText` (but instead just using `text`) this method doesn't take into account the `numberOfLines` property.
2. `boundingRectWithSize` returns fractions of points. If you are using the values returned from this method for layouts, you should probably `ceilf` the width and height.