# How to get the count/length of string displayed in UITextView?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, uitextview

I have given a large text to display in different text views. So i have set the whole text content in an `NSTextContainer`.Then added a `NSLayoutManager`. Created NSTextContainers for different `UITextViews`. I got continuous text in different `TextViews` . But i cant limit the no of textviews using a condition.

My problem is i want to create textviews accroding to the content. And the content may vary.I tried to create a condition bw whole text content & textview's content. But even though each contains different text, all `textview.text length` returns the same value as the length  of the entire text content !!!!

Here is the code>>

```
-(void)paginate:(NSString*)chapterData WithSize:(CGRect)frame
{
    int stringLength,totalTextViewsTextLength;
    totalTextViewsTextLength=0;


    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:chapterData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    NSAttributedString *temp=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];


    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:temp];
    NSLayoutManager *textLayout = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:textLayout];

    stringLength=[temp length];


    while (totalTextViewsTextLength<stringLength)               // checks whether all the content has been added to textview or not
    {

        NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:frame.size];
        [textLayout addTextContainer:textContainer];

//        textContainer.lin
        UITextView *textView=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:frame textContainer:textContainer];
        textView.tag=textviewCount;



        // Store textviews in array
        [pagedData addObject:textView];


        totalTextViewsTextLength+=[textView.text length];
        textviewCount++;

    }

}
```

What i need is to get the length of text displayed in each textview(that contains different textcontainers ) ??????

Comment: txtfield.text.length. form this u will get it.

Comment: @ShreyanshShah . tat gives the whole size of the text in text view . But i need only the text that has been displayed in textview

Comment: So do you want the total height of the text which is displayed in textview???

Comment: @NiravPatel hi, Not the height. I want to get the length of the text displayed in a textview

Comment: So do you want number of characters displayed in textview??

Comment: this this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6067803/1403732)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to limit the content in UITextView in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644583/how-to-limit-the-content-in-uitextview-in-ios)

Comment: @DivyaBhalodiya I was trying to simplify my question and what i need is solution for issue . . . can u help me

Comment: @DivyaBhalodiya and what i am trying to do is get the exact answer , so that others with the same issue will get the solution

Answer (score 1):

I get you point what exactly, you want. 
You have fix height of the text view, in this textView you want to set text, right ? If its right, then use following approach :

Suppose your textView height is 450

1, Calculate height of the your text, that you want to display in textView

here ft  is your font size  i.e  `UIFont * ft = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];`

```
 CGSize expectedSize = [textview.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:ft}];

    float height= 0; 

    height = expectedLabelSize.height
```

2, check height of the textView with your text that you want to display in textView

```
if(height > 'your textview height') 
 {
     // add you code here 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for understanding my issue

Answer (score 0):

to get count of visible characters first use code in this answer [ios - how to find what is the visible range of text in UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11842530/1403732) then just get `length` of`NSRange`

Comment: i tired it. But it returns null

Answer (score 0):

To get length of text in textview use:

```
 int textLength = [someTextView.text length]
```

To get length excluding white spaces use:

```
  int textLength= [someTextView.text  stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                         [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]length];
```

**UPDATE**   To get length after every character entered u must have to write your code in following method

This will called for every character you type.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{   
  NSUInteger textLength = [textField.text length];
  NSLog(@"Textfield Length :%ld",textLength);
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi, as i specified i want to get the length of the text displayed. Not the entire text length

Comment: I ve already told i am not trying to enter text , but display text from existing file

Answer (score -2):

use following way, before set text to the textview, check length of the string :

```
NSString *textEntered = [[[textview.text copy] autorelease] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

if([textEntered length] > 450) {
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:kMoreThan450CharactersForQuestion delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                [alertView release];
            }
```

Comment: Divya , you have just removed all white spaces and counted the text list. And limited the count to 450. How it will be correct when a text contains many paragraphs or no paragraphs ???