# How can I bold an html text for my label in Swift3

Tags: swift, swift3, uilabel, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I have only a label in the center of one view. I want to bold some part of my label. I can do it, but when I do it, I lose the size of my label.
I found some thread, but no one could help me with this problem size.

Here is the code I use:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
        data: "I'm a normal text and <b>this is my bold part . </b>And I'm again in the normal text".data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil)
    myLabel.attributedText = attrStr
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43890839/3752143

Comment: The solution you give don't work for me, when I do it I loose all my bold

Comment: I have voted to reopen the question due to the fact that this one is asking about bolding text with html tags. The suggested duplicated question is asking about bolding a given string within other one.

Answer (score 0):

After you bold text, [re-calculate the size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409897/how-to-calculate-the-height-of-an-nsattributedstring-with-given-width-in-ios-6) of attributed label using `boundingRectWithSize:option:context`