# How should I determine the height of an NSAttributedString for a fixed width

Tags: ios7, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have an attributed string with "*Date:* **Heading** - Description."
The Date, Heading, and Description text values are dynamically generated, and all have different attributed fonts which I've assigned to the appropriate substring.

How should I determine the total width, and then consequentially the determine the height for a given width which this content should fill?

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282629/how-to-get-height-for-nsattributedstring-at-a-fixed-width) SO post but it is from 2010 and a more current solution seems like it would be available.

Additionally, how should the width of an attributed string with content changing text style by substring be determined?  The iOS7 [sizeWithAttributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithAttributes:) method seems to apply the attributes for the entire string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an attributed string, so the place to look is the NSAttributedString documentation. In particular:

[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/boundingRectWithSize:options:context:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/boundingRectWithSize%3aoptions%3acontext%3a)

As to your last paragraph: simply make this a mutable attributed string, change the styles as desired, and proceed as above.